# Temperature of R-N Black Hole by Euclideanising the Metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, temperature, reissner-nordstrom-metric

How to derive the temperature of the Reissner–Nordstrom black hole by euclideanising the metric?

Comment: I have edited the tags and added homework-and exercises in them. Can the question be taken off hold now?